# using analytics.js and react-ga

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-router

I'm setting up Google Analytics for the first time and opted to use react-ga for it's simple integration into react-router and our React components. My question is, do I also need to set up the app with Google's analytics.js, or can I simply use the react-ga package? Is there any aspect of analytics.js that will be important to include?

Comment: I just took a brief look at the `react-ga` package, and I wouldn't recommend using it. I see zero value it adds over the [analytics.js](https://devsite.googleplex.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) library Google Analytics provides. Using `react-ga` will mean you have more things to learn and you users will need to download more code.

Comment: that's interesting, thank you. I guess the main reason I was looking at it was to solve this issue with tracking changes on single page applications in GA.

Comment: You don't need a library to do that. The implementation is actually relatively straightforward and is described in [this guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications). According to the `react-ga` documentation, tracking SPA page changes requires basically the exact same code that guides recommends.

Comment: thanks @PhilipWalton. I see in the documentation that there is also a plugin called autotrack. Do you have any experience with that package?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it :) https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/graphs/contributors

Comment: If all you want to use autotrack for is the SPA stuff, it may be easier to just do that manually. If you want to use some of the other plugins/functionality, I recommend it (and use it myself).

Comment: Ah perfect! I'm excited to try it out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) maintainer here. Thank you for your interest in `react-ga`.

React GA helps you to fetch Google's `analytics.js` and initializes `analytics.js` with the key that you provide to it in the `ReactGA.initialize` call. Hence, no you do not need to explicitly add `analytics.js` yourself and you can simply use `react-ga` package.

The value of `react-ga` lies in a React + GA integrated `OutboundLink` component and the parameter validations. As of present, React GA is a thin wrapper around the `analytics.js` calls but it helps you validate the parameters you pass into it and also provides a `debug` flag where you can see `console.log`s of events being sent to Google Analytics.

Comment: It fails to work in React 16 with React-router-dom, any update on when support will be available?